# Simulink 'to file - Block' :: How to add date / time to filename

Tags: matlab, simulink

I save the data from my simulation with the to file block to a .mat file. 
When I start a new simulation, Simulink will overwrite the file if I dont set a new filename in the blocks properties.

Is it possible to add automaticly the current date / time to the filename? For the later usecase, i would be to extensive to set a filename for every new simulation manually.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a callback that will be called whenever a simulation is started and update the filename pointed by the ToFile block

In your callback function (my_callback.m) :

```
block = find_system(bdroot,'Name','NameOfTheToFileBlock');
if ~isempty(block)
    file_name = strcat('filename_', datestr(now, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS'), '.mat');
    set_param(block{1}, 'Filename', file_name);
end
```

You can setup the callback programmatically that way :

```
set_param('your_model','StartFcn','my_callback');
```